# How do I listen for AWS SQS messages in the background of my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to asynchronously poll messages in the background of my rails application. Shoryuken doesn't work because I want my rails app to listen for incoming HTTP requests too.

Comment: Why Shoryuken does not work? Shoryuken runs in a separated process from your Rails app, it should not impact/change anything in your Rails app.

Comment: @PabloCantero - thanks for the comment. We deploy our services in docker, so we'd prefer to have everything wrapper into the same process. usually the approach to this is just have 2 containers - one for rails, one for queue processing, that way each has its own process, but considering how light weight the queue load is in this particular app, it wasn't worth the ops and computing overhead of taking that approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an initializer in `config/initializers` like so:

```
# Allows the thread to crash our app for us
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
Thread.new do
    queue_url = "..."
    poller = Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.new(queue_url)
    poller.poll do |msg|
      puts msg.body
    end
end
```

You can process the message through a more complex job using [Active Job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html):

create the job like so:
`rails g job process_a_message`

then in the poller block:

```
    poller.poll do |msg|
      ProcessAMessageJob.perform_later msg.body
    end
```

Comment: Did anyone actually try this piece with ActiveJob?  From Rails console, the initializer worked fine for us but with the server running in daemon mode, the thread appears to crash after an initial consumption...

Comment: Got the same issue....