# Background thread appears to lock on Rails using AWS QueuePoller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, amazon-web-services, delayed-job

We have a need to consume from a an SQS queue in our Rails application; for this we've chosen to use [SQS QueuePoller](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SQS/QueuePoller.html)

Following the response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482560/how-do-i-listen-for-aws-sqs-messages-in-the-background-of-my-rails-app) that was labeled too broad, we created the following in an initializer:

```
require 'json'
ENV['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'
if Rails.env.production?
  Thread.abort_on_exception = true
  Thread.new do
    CUSTOM_LOGGER = [Custom Logger Defn...]
    queue_url = "...."
    poller = Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.new(queue_url)

    poller.before_request do |stats|
      CUSTOM_LOGGER.info("requests: #{stats.request_count}")
      CUSTOM_LOGGER.info("messages: #{stats.received_message_count}")
      CUSTOM_LOGGER.info("last-timestamp: #{stats.last_message_received_at}")
    end

    CUSTOM_LOGGER.info("Start polling!")
    poller.poll do |msg|
      CUSTOM_LOGGER.debug("Received message: "+msg.body)
      begin
        json_msg = JSON.parse(msg.body)
        job_name = json_msg["Message"]
        job_name.constantize.perform_later if defined? job_name.constantize
        CUSTOM_LOGGER.debug("Submitted to delayed job: "+job_name)
      rescue => e
        throw :skip_delete
      end
    end
    CUSTOM_LOGGER.info("Finished polling - exiting thread!")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
  end
end
```

This yielded strange behavior - when running the rails server (daemon/production) mode, the poller seemed to consume all the messages currently on the queue then stopped (no log output for the thread finishing polling, just seems stuck).  However, if we run from the Rails console, the thread seems to move along happily consuming from SQS indefinitely.

Any particular reason that a background thread would get stuck/die in Unicorn right off the bat?

Comment: Related to unicorn's forking perhaps? (When you fork a process only the thread that calls fork continues executing in the new process)

Comment: I wasn't aware that Thread.new was forking unicorn - though admittedly I do not know enough about unicorn.

Comment: Thread.new doesn't cause forking but unicorn itself does fork, which will interrupt threads. If this is the problem you'd be able to reproduce it with a thread that just writes to a log file or something every second (to exclude SQS as a reason for the problem)